# How can I find related learndash course id from woocommerce product object?

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have woocommerce integrated with LearnDash. Now I am trying to get the selected course (related course) from the woocommerce product object or any other way (by woocommerce product id). There must be a way as buying the product unlocks the course. Just cannot find it.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. It is for anyone who might find it helpful:

```
get_post_meta(ID, '_related_course', true);
```

Here ID will be the WooCommerce Product ID. It will output the course id in array. Just need to extract the ID from there.